# How to set the "more" tab bar's edit view's navigation bar black?

Tags: iphone, ios, ipad, uinavigationbar, uitabcontroller

I am trying to set all my tab bar's navigation bars UIBarStyleBlack.

I could also achieve this for the "more" tab bar with this:

```
tabBarController.moreNavigationController.navigationBar.barStyle = UIBarStyleBlack;
```

The problem is that when you click its top Edit button to customize the tabs it presents a new modal controller with a standard blue navigation bar, and I can't manage to set it UIBarStyleBlack.

Comment: Found this page [link](http://runmad.com/blog/2010/01/coloring-fun-with-morenavigationcontroller-and-it/)

Comment: Seems like I can catch the modal edit view implementing this tab bar delegate method
    - (void)tabBarController:(UITabBarController *)controller willBeginCustomizingViewControllers:(NSArray *)viewControllers

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The link has a slightly hackie solution that involves listening to when the modal view will appear.

[Colouring fun with moreNavigationController](http://runmad.com/blog/2010/01/coloring-fun-with-morenavigationcontroller-and-it/)

Until iOS5+ enables us to do it in a cleaner way.

Comment: done it in a major app and did not get rejected -> works fine.

Comment: It's not really that hacky. It's not like you're swizzling or using private APIs. Anyway, just wanted to comment that all this can be done with UIAppearance on iOS 5 and up.

Answer (score 2):

Swift - customizing Tabbar -> More menu -> Edit view (navigation bar and content view).

```
override func tabBar(_ tabBar: UITabBar, willBeginCustomizing items: [UITabBarItem]) {
    for (index, subView) in view.subviews.enumerated() {
        subView.backgroundColor = UIColor.black
        if index == 1 {
            subView.tintColor = UIColor.green
            for customSubView in subView.subviews {
                if let navBar = customSubView as? UINavigationBar {
                    navBar.isTranslucent = false
                    navBar.barTintColor = UIColor.black
                    navBar.tintColor = .white
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

This is what worked for me.

Answer (score 0):

Sublcass `UITabBarController` and overwrite these methods:

```
- (void)tabBar:(UITabBar *)tabBar willEndCustomizingItems:(NSArray<UITabBarItem *> *)items changed:(BOOL)changed {
    self.moreNavigationController.navigationBar.barStyle = UIBarStyleBlack;
}

- (void)tabBar:(UITabBar *)tabBar didBeginCustomizingItems:(NSArray<UITabBarItem *> *)items {
    self.moreNavigationController.navigationBar.barStyle = UIBarStyleDefault;
}
```